# JavaScript: window.location() # error

Tags: javascript, parameters

I have a problem with JavaScript. I want to send parameters to php file but if there is a # character in the paramater, php is giving an error. This error is like below;

```
Undefined index: keyword in C:\xampp\htdocs\TweetProject\test.php on line 2
```

My JavaScript code:

```
   </script>
    function sendParam(){
            keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
            var url = "test.php?keyword=" + keyword;  
            window.open(url);
    }
    </script>
```

My PHP Code:

```
    <?php
    $keyword = $_GET["keyword"];
    echo $keyword;
    ?>
```

Comment: It's your PHP error. How can you get keyword in PHP? Your PHP code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add onto what the other answer said (and to give you the code):

```
   </script>
    function sendParam(){
            keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("keyword").value);
            var url = "test.php?keyword=" + keyword;  
            window.open(url);
    }
    </script>
```

and your php:

```
<?php
$keyword = $_GET["keyword"];
echo $keyword;
?>
```

Comment: i've tried your code Mr. Trevor but problem is doesn't solve :(

Comment: Ok try this: inbtween the var url line and the window.open line add this: 
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
let me know if it works.. if it doesnt tell me the error

Comment: php file doesn't open. Error 403

Comment: and what link does it put in the url

Comment: i think problem is http:get method. when i send parameters in the form, there is no an error, return

Comment: I know your problem I think

Comment: becuase the parameter is no longer keyword it is now: latitude, longitude, ect .. so if you do 
<?php
$keyword = $_GET["latitude"];
echo $keyword;
?>

Comment: as your php ... and that should echo your latitude

Comment: could you tell me my problem? i've tried for 2 ours on that.

Answer (score 1):

`#` indicates the start of the fragment identifier. If you want to include it, or any other special character, as data then you have to percent encode it.

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).